# import module relative to source root directory in Cypress tests

Tags: cypress, vite, alias

In my app that's build with Vite I can import modules relative to the source root directory with

```
import { randomId } from '@/utils/string-utils'
```

This works because in my `vite.config.js` I've defined this alias

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    '@': path.resolve(__dirname, "./src")
  }
}
```

But Cypress doesn't know anything about this, so if I want to import the module above in a Cypress file, I have to use something like

```
import { randomId } from '../../../../src/utils/string-utils'
```

This is tedious and error-prone, because if the Cypress directory structure changed, the import may no longer work. Is it possible to define something similar to the `@` alias that will work in Cypress?

Answer (score 2):

I got a Javascript version going with `@cypress/webpack-preprocessor` (Note the Cypress docs for this util are out of date).

Requires installs as follows:

- @cypress/webpack-preprocessor
- webpack
- @babel/core
- @babel/preset-env
- babel-loader

This is the minimal `cypress.config.js`.

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents (on, config) {
      const webpackPreprocessor = require("@cypress/webpack-preprocessor")
      // @src alias
      const options = {
        webpackOptions: {             
          resolve: {                 
            alias: {                     
              '@src': path.resolve(__dirname, './src')              
            },             
          },         
        },     
        watchOptions: {},
      }
      on('file:preprocessor', webpackPreprocessor(options))
      return config
    },
  },
})
```

In an example test file

```js
import { randomId } from '@src/utils/string-utils'

it('tests import aliases via webpack', () => {
  cy.log(randomId)
})
```

The random thingy from `src/utils/string-utils.js`

```
export const randomId = 'not-so-random'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you need to  create a tsconfig.json file in your Cypress directory and configure the baseUrl and paths options.  see below

```
// cypress/tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "../src", // Set the base directory for resolving modules
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["*"] // Define aliases here
    }
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts"]
}
```

then you can use it below

```
// cypress/integration/test-file.ts
import { randomId } from '@/utils/string-utils'; // Use the alias here
```

if your project is in Javascript

you can create a custom alias for importing modules in Cypress by configuring the Webpack bundler used by Cypress. To set up an alias, you can use the webpack.config.js file within your Cypress directory.

Create a webpack.config.js file in your Cypress directory ( at cypress/webpack.config.js) .

In the webpack.config.js file, configure the aliases by defining a resolve section in the Webpack configuration. You can set up an alias that points to your project's source directory. For example:

```
// cypress/weboack.config.js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  config.resolve.alias = {
    '@': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'), // Adjust the path as needed
  };

  // Other configurations...

  return config;
};
```

usage

Comment: How would you do it for a Javascript project?

Comment: updated my ans for javascript.

Comment: Thanks - feels like somethings missing?